# Pass some random value returned from a function to another function

Tags: python

I am stuck in a situation where I need to pass some value (which is always be random/different) returned from a function to another function, and the sequence in which the functions will be called is undefined as it will be figured at run-time based on user inputs.

For example,

```
def func1(some_value):
    # Use some_value for whatever purpose
    # Some code
    return some_random_value

def func2(some_value):
    # Use some_value for whatever purpose
    # Some code
    return some_random_value

def func3(some_value):
    # Use some_value for whatever purpose
    # Some code
    return some_random_value
```

So let's assume if `func2` is called first, any initial/default value is passed as parameter `some_value` and the function will return `some_random_value`. Now, I don't know which function will be called next, but whatever function is called the `some_random_value` returned from the previous function (in this case `func2`) should be passed as parameter `some_value` to the next called function (let it be `func1`). And this process goes on and on.

What could be the recommended way to achieve this? Should this be done using a global variable whose value is amended each time a function runs to store the function's return value? If yes, then how?

*More specifically*

A CLI will allow the user to choose some action and an appropriate function will be called according to this action. The last returned value from a function should be in the memory till the application ends. After a function performs it's task, it'll return a value. That value is required when any other function is called using CLI action. Again, the next function will process some data using the last function's return value, and then return some processed value, which later will be used by the next function or CLI action.

I was thinking like instead of returning the value from any of those functions, create a global variable with the default value:

```
common_data = 'some string'
```

And then in every function definition, add:

```
global common_data
common_data = 'new processed string'
```

This will ensure any next function call will be passed the value last saved in common_data by the previous function.

But this seems to be a non-recommend solution, at least I think so.

Please allow me to edit or elaborate this question if I am unable to explain my situation properly.

Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with just passing the return value of one function as a parameter to the next function call? That seems to do exactly what you want and the order is determined by the caller

Comment: @UnholySheep Suppose that func2 is run first, and then I don't know which function will be executed next. So don't I need to store the func2's returned value in some variable to pass it as a parameter to next function call? May be I am too confused that I am missing some basic concepts.

Comment: There is not enough information about the life-time of this data, how the other functions are called, and how this random  data relates to the calls. These functions could be moved to a class where the random data is an instance variable available to all of the methods. But that only works for some types of designs. I think this will be closed as too broad because there really is no way to answer it.

Comment: @tdelaney I have edited the question and tried to be more specific, if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I will deliver on this recursion error. ^^

```
from random import choice
from random import randint


def get_fs(f):
    return [x for x in (func1, func2, func3) if x != f]


def func1(some_value, fs):
    # Use some_value for whatever purpose
    # Some code
    f = choice(fs)
    print("func1", f.__name__)
    return f(randint(1,10), get_fs(func1))


def func2(some_value, fs):
    # Use some_value for whatever purpose
    # Some code

    f = choice(fs)
    print("func2", f.__name__)
    return f(randint(1,10), get_fs(func2))


def func3(some_value, fs):
    # Use some_value for whatever purpose
    # Some code

    f = choice(fs)
    print("func3", f.__name__)
    return f(randint(1,10), get_fs(func3))


def main():
    functions = [func2, func3]
    func1(randint(1,10), functions)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```